# String is showing different windows and Unix system special charactors are getting formatting

Tags: java, xml, windows, unix

I am uploading xml file into server using java API there i am reading the xml file at the server using parser. So the xml file one string having the special characters that string formatting which we can't readable.Please find the below is the input xml tag from windowsand out put xml tag in `UNIX`.

input Windows:

```
<ns:details>CN=Jiri Manak, SERIALNUMBER=A417280, GIVENNAME=Jiri, SU=Maňák, O=Atos, C=SK</ns:details>
```

output UNIX:

```
<ns:details>CN=Jiri Manak, SERIALNUMBER=A417280, GIVENNAME=Jiri, SU=MaÅÃ¡k, O=Atos, C=SK</ns:details>
```

Could you please help me how to avoid these formatting strings.

I want to see both input and output are the same.

Thanks
Regards
Vijaya Kumar

Comment: It seems that your file is encoded in Windows 1252 codepage (variant of ISO-8859-1 or Latin1), and that your Unix server is expecting UTF8. **You** have to know what the encoding should be and where the conversion must be done.

Comment: Hi Mandar  i have added a encoding type in xml file : encoding="UTF-8" still i am having the same problem. for your reference i am attaching the xml file.

Comment: What I see is that you *declared* the file to be UTF8 encoded. You should use a tool that supports different encoding to control the actual encoding. [gvim](http://www.vim.org) is know to be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For reference i am attaching the input xml file.

Thanks
Vijay